# Java: Count unique values in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

In a `Map<K,V>` I want to know how many unique values of `V` there are. Is there something like `getValueSet()` so that I can then get the size of this set? In pseudo code:

```
Map<K,V> myMap = ...//initiate Map;
Set<V> valueSet = myMap.getValueSet()
int numberUniqueB = valueSet.size();
```

Unfortunately there is no `getValueSet` method. Alternatively I can iterate through the list myself like this:

```
Set<V> mySet = new HashSet<V>();
    for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry : myMap.entrySet()){
    V value = entry.getValue();
    mySet.add(value);
    }
int countUniqueB = mySet.size();
```

But this seems like I'm reinventing the wheel. Is there something in `Collections` or elsewhere that already does what I'm looking for? If not, is there a more efficient way to get the result than how I have it above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java 8 has been around a while now:

```
int count = myMap.values().stream().distinct().count();
```

Comment: I haven't used streams before but this works and looks good. Until now Java 8 has only been "Java.Time" to me (and worthwhile for that alone). I have some reading to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The constructors of most `Collection` implementations take another `Collection` as a parameter, so you can feed the values of the `Map` directly into the `HashSet` constructor:

```
int count = new HashSet<V>(myMap.values()).size();
```

Computationally, this is as expensive as your code, but since the values in a `Map` are not usually stored in a `Set` - so you have to create a `Set` anyway to find the unique count (or, optionally, sort the values, but that will probably be slower).

Comment: This works great, and you were first but I think I need to embrace the Java 8 answer from @Bohemian. Thanks though, much better code than mine was!

Comment: @Ben: I agree; embrace Java 8 as much as possible :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want a set containing ONLY the values :

```
Map<K,V> myMap = ...//initiate Map;
Set<V> set = new HashSet<V>(myMap.values());
int numberUniqueB = set.size();
```

Read about Interface `Map<K,V>`,Check this out [Java MAP Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()).

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the `.size()` method of a `Collection`.

```
Map<K, V> myMap = ...
Collection<V> valueSet = myMap.values();
int size = valueSet.size();
```